# Pulling IP from File Without brackets

Tags: python, regex

I have an hosts file such as

us-east-1 34.192.0.54

us-west-1 50.18.56.1

While trying to take out just IP for Ping test i am using below code:

```
    hosts = open('hosts','r')
    for line in hosts:
        temp=line.split()[1:]
        print(temp)
```

But it id displaying me ['34.192.0.54'] as the output, but i just need

```
    34.192.0.54
```

to run a ping test. What else can i add in the code to get the desired out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `:`in your split.

**Hosts file:**

```
    us-east-1 34.192.0.54
    us-west-1 50.18.56.1
```

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

hosts = open('hosts','r')
for line in hosts:
    temp=line.split()[1]
    print temp
```

**Output:**

```
34.192.0.54
50.18.56.1
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using workmanager with max/min thread constraint with corresponding OSB service ?
16 consumers are default for a queue for per managed server. if there are more than 1 OSB services connected to same queue then consumer count would be multiple of 16 .
only possibility would be if there is some WM or any other application is connected to this queue.